# Count distinct three digit numbers using digits 6,7,8,9 only once in each number?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $3$ digit numbers can be found using 3 of the digits $6,7,8,9$ without repetition in each number?

Answer (score 3):

First digit: $4$ numbers to choose from, $4$ choices.

Second digit: $3$ numbers to choose from, since one as already been chosen: $3$ choices remain.

Third digit: $2$ choices. (Only two numbers remain unchosen.)

Total number of three digit numbers that have no repeating digits, using the product rule: $$4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 24.$$